# Customizing the API Manager URL(s) - Windows

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

So i'm trying to change the default URL for WSO2 features i.e. Publisher, Carbon, Store from localhost to, lets say, myDomain.com.

I've looked for it in the WSO2 documentation but i keep finding this article over and over again

- https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM210/Customize+the+API+Store+and+Gateway+URLs

The problem with this is that it has linux-based (i suppose) commands listed that cannot be applied to windows.

I've also tried to change the host < HostName > and < MGT HostName > tags in the carbon.xml of the WSO2 product but it does not respond and display the page AT ALL! just works with the localhost. thats it

Any ideas or options for the windows end? Thanks

Comment: The "commands" are effectively installing and creating a reverse proxy with hostname mapping. You can do the same on the Windows system (e.g. install Apache httpd server for Windows) and setup a reverse proxy configuration. That is outside scope of the documentation. If you need I could post you my configuration for that Apache httpd

Comment: And I forgot - when  you change the domain name - you need to change the hostnames and ports in the api-manager.xml as well

Comment: @gusto2 Thank you for your comment. Why the apache httpd server? Why not iis? and why is it outside the scope of wso2's documentation? so many questions!

Comment: @gusto2 AND please do post your configuration for the apache httpd!

Comment: @gusto2 THIRDLY, why do we need to set up a reverse proxy configuration when the base URL for wso2 will be changed? Your explanation, as per my perception, points to the fact that the reverse proxy will be setup just to route the requests to the wso2's base URL???!

Comment: ..which is localhost? btw iis has the specified feature as well. https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/carlosag/2010/04/01/setting-up-a-reverse-proxy-using-iis-url-rewrite-and-arr/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Yes, the commands given in the doc are for linux. But what those commands do is installing `nginx`. So you can ignore those commands, and install nginx in windows.

NGinx configurations given in the doc will be the same for any OS.

2) If you add a hostname to `<HostName>` and `<MGT HostName>` tags, you need to have IP to hostname mapping somewhere. I think there is a host file in windows for that.

Comment: so i've installed the nginx as you mentioned, would changing the specified tags in the carbon.xml be enough or should i follow the steps mentioned on this: https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM210/Customize+the+API+Store+and+Gateway+URLs

Comment: Changing carbon.xml will only change the hostname. If you want to change the entire url, you need to configure a reverse proxy like nginx.

Comment: how is nginx helpful in that regard?

Comment: the default publisher url is `https://hostname:port/publisher`. with nginx you can have something like `https://hostname:port/public/publisher/portal`

Comment: I believe for `/public/publisher/portal`  you'd need to update the jaggery confing for the application (publisher) too.     @AimalKhan we used only the proxy server, updates in the api-manager.xml are needed, but no updates in the registry

Comment: Yes. It's mentioned in the doc.

Comment: @bha the document could have been better by adding a version for windows as well! secondly, since i cannot execute this sudo openssl req -x509 -nodes -days 365 -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout /etc/nginx/ssl/nginx.key -out /etc/nginx/ssl/nginx.crt to get a certificate, should this be helpful? keytool -export -alias certalias -file test_sampleapp_org.crt -keystore newkeystore.jks to get a self signed certificate?

Comment: @bha there's also no nginx directory in my apim so i suppose it requires some settings as well? as mentioned in the linux command /etc/nginx/ssl/nginx

Comment: @gusto2 i'm stuck at this one thing that if we're to change the base URL of the api manager, why do we need to set up a reverse proxy for that? would'nt the tomcat server just sort that out for us?

Comment: in fact  - you don't need any proxy. change the cabon.xml (do not forget to place the hostnames in the hosts file), check that urls in api-manager.xml are valid and you should be good to go. however - proxy is the best practice as maybe you want to run on port 443 (on Linux you need root privileges for that), you may not want to expose all apps (e.g. we let publisher accessible only from internal network), infrastructure team can manage ssl themselves, etc..  if it doesn't work, you should see logs (wso2carbon.log) or browser console to see what doesn't work for you

Comment: @aimalkhan for the certificates - you may want to use real ssl certificates. the steps described are for linux (you may have openssl on windows as well). the articles are assuming you know how to work with keystores and certificates and you know what are you doing (regardless used system)

Comment: @bha turns out that you were right! i only had to change the <HostName> and <MGT HostName> tags in carbon.xml and put the wso2 product on a DNS mapped server. I'll post a more detailed answer here!